# Label point features based on clock position?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, maplex

I have recently been tasked with collecting data on the position in which sewer lines enter manholes for a local government Public Works department. To collect these points, field workers are using the collector app to drop a point on top of a manhole, and fill in a field that indicates the clock position that the lines are entering the manhole (Based on a North orientation).

So now that I have points that have a clock position field with values such as "3" if the line was coming in directly from the east, or "9" if the line entered from the west, I am wondering how I can label these points.

In essence, I am looking to assign label position based on the value of this clock position field.

Is this possible with ArcGIS Pro Maplex label engine?

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, I created 12 different label classes. Each of these is driven by the value of the Clock Position field, so by setting the position and offset each value is placed in the appropriate clock position. However now I am trying to figure out how to publish these label classes so I can use them in web maps.